# phpMyadmin backup and restore database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have database named **s3d_db** in my web hosting plan on godaddy and i want to backup this database and restore it in another database in VPS plan on godaddy where the new database name is **webapp_s3d_db**. So i used the export option in **s3d_db** database and than import option into new **webapp_s3d_db** database using default option for both export and import but i found that one of the tables in old database has ~49,023 Rows and the same table in new database has ~90,678 Rows. How i can do this task in a proper way ?

Comment: Try exporting the tables separately? Have you checked the DB dump produced? Is it truncated? It may be that there's a size limit on the downloadable file and exporting the entire DB at once surpassed that limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ~ character means phpMyAdmin is approximating the number of rows so this may not be an issue.

To export your database I would suggest you use the command line rather than phpMyAdmin:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u USERANME -p DATABASE_NAME > output.sql
```

Run that, you'll be prompted for your database password and then you'll get output.sql containing your database

You can then import this using ..

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME --no-create-db < output.sql
```